# AWK get specificic pattern

Tags: awk

I have lines like this:

```
Volume.Free_IBM_LUN59_28D:      2072083693568
```

I would like to get only IBM_LUN59_28D from this line using awk.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to do substitutions on each input line, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'Volume.Free_IBM_LUN59_28D:      2072083693568' | awk '
...> {
...>     sub (".*Free_", "");
...>     sub (":.*", "");
...>     print
...> }'
IBM_LUN59_28D
```

That command crosses multiple lines for readability but, if you're operating on a file and not *too* concerned about readability, you can just use the compressed version:

```
awk '{sub(".*Free_","");sub(":.*","");print}' inputFile
```

If you're amenable to non-`awk` solutions, you could also use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/.*Free_//' -e 's/:.*//' inputFile
```

---

Note that both those solutions rely on your (somewhat sparse) test data. If your definition of "like" includes preceding textual segments *other* than `Free_` or subsequent characters *other* than `:`, some more work may be needed.

For example, if you wanted the string between the first `_` and the first `:`, you could use:

```
awk '{sub("[^_]*_","");sub(":.*","");print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With **sed**:

```
sed 's/[^_]*_\(.*\):.*/\1/'
```

Search for sequence of non `_` characters followed by `_` (this will match `Volume.Free_`), then another sequence of characters (this will match IBM_LUN59_28D, we group this for future use), followed by `:` and any char sequence. Substitute with the saved pattern (`\1`). That's it.

**Sample:**

```
$ echo "Volume.Free_IBM_LUN59_28D:      2072083693568" | sed 's/[^_]*_\(.*\):.*/\1/'
IBM_LUN59_28D
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk -F"Free_" 'NF>1{split($2,a,":");print a[1]}'
```

Eks:

```
echo "Volume.Free_IBM_LUN59_28D:      2072083693568" | awk -F"Free_" 'NF>1{split($2,a,":");print a[1]}'
IBM_LUN59_28D
```

It divides the line by `Free_`.
If line then have more than one field `NF>1` then:
Split second field bye `:` and print first part `a[1]`

Answer (score 0):

With **awk**:

```
echo "$val" | awk -F: '{print $1}' | awk -F. '{print $2}' | awk '{print substr($0,6)}'
```

where the given string is in $val.